# How to undo fdisk new partition on ext4 file system?

Tags: centos, partition, lvm, fdisk

I have a LVM called /dev/data/files on a VM of mine.
I allocated 50 GB on it and wanted to extend this LVM...

So, instead of using lvextend command which i forgot to use i did the following:

```
fdisk /dev/data/files
Used N option to create a partition
Writed changes...
```

So then i restarted the server but the size didnt change.
I didnt know how fdisk worked so i believe that i created a new partition on that file system...

My question is:
Is it safe to delete this partition i created and then use lvextend to extend the LVM disk the correct way? Like if i enter fdisk again and choose to delete the partition, will i lose any files? Or is it ok to remove it?

Thanks!

Comment: just to be sure: `/dev/data/files` an LVM *volume*, right? So, you just created a partition table on a logical volume, which doesn't make much sense, and if there was a file system on it, you've overwritten its beginning. Whether or not that is recoverable depends on the file system.

Comment: If your file system is not mounted, you should try `fsck.ext4 /dev/data/files`… with some luck, it will find a superblock backup, but the `-b` option ask you where it is… The command may not be able to find such a block automatically. If your file system is mounted, you should backup your files now… you may not be able to mount it again.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller . Yes, it is a LVM volume... I used the command fdisk /dev/data/files and created a new partition using some space of this lvm, which then created another partition called /dev/data/files1 . What i want to do is: Remove this partition i created and just extend the lvm size...

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer My LVM is mounted.

Comment: @RaulChiarella could you tell us for what *purpose* you're putting a partition table on an LVM volume? That seems **really** odd to me.

Comment: Sorry, i just wanted to extend the volume size. Thats it... But i still couldnt figure this out, but since its another topic i will probably open a new question regarding "How to extend LVM Ext4 size"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two sectors in an ext4 filesystem [are not used](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/overview.html).

If you create a DOS partition table with only primary partitions then those writes affect the first sector only and no filesystem data has been destroyed.

If a logical partition has been created then it is possible that data has been destroyed (depending on the position of the partition).

If a GPT has been created then the filesystem superblock has been destroyed. In that case the device could not be mounted any more.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. So, i had this ext4 partition which directed to /mnt/data... Then i ran the commands fdisk /dev/data/files and created a new partition using the space of that mount. Now i have another partition called /dev/data/files1 but i want to remove that new partition /dev/data/files1 and instead just extend the size of the ext4 mounted partition...

Comment: @RaulChiarella Run `fdisk /dev/data/files` again and delete the partition. Or just zero the first two sectors (you may want to backup them if you don't trust my info...): `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/data/files bs=512 count=2`. But that is not even necessary. You can just ignore what you did. Unless you created a filesystem on `/dev/data/files1`...

Comment: Thanks, i deleted it and nothing of harm happened to my files.